# automatic conversion using a constructor

Tags: c++, class

I have these 2 classes:

```
     class iterator {
     public:
            Node<K,V>* n;
            iterator():n(NULL){}
            iterator(const iterator& iter):n(iter.n){}
            explicit iterator(Node<K,V>* nodePtr):n(nodePtr) {}
            void operator=(const iterator& iter);
            void operator++();
            Node<K,V>& operator*();
            bool operator!=(const iterator& iter);
            K& operator[](const Key& k)const;
            V& operator[](const Val& v)const;
    };
    //----const_iterator-class---------------------------


    class const_iterator : public iterator {
    public:
            const Node<K,V>* n;
            const_iterator():n(NULL);
            const_iterator(const const_iterator& iter):n(iter.n){}
            const_iterator(const iterator& iter):n(iter.n){}
            explicit const_iterator(const Node<K,V>* node):n(node){}
            void operator=(const const_iterator& iter){
                    n=iter.n;
            }
            void operator++(){
                    n = n->next;
            }
    };
```

I want to automatically convert `iterator` to `const_iterator` in case a method gets the wrong type as a parameter. I'm trying to use:

```
 const_iterator(iterator& iter):n(iter.n){}
```

why do I get a segmentation fault when trying to access what's inside iter.n (the value pointed by n) after it is converted from iterator to const_iterator?

Comment: Please clear and format the code

Comment: You're taking the parameter as a non-`const` reference, which means that you can't use this parameter to convert temporary objects. Can you show us the exact code where you're getting the error?

Comment: for(Map<int,int>::const_iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it){

Comment: m.begin() return iterator, I want it to be automatically converted to const_iterator

Comment: Maybe it is easier to write `operator const_iterator()` for `iterator`. You can then easily construct a const_iterator without the need for a `const iterator&` argument

Comment: I need the conversion to happen automatically without a function or an operator

Answer (score 0):

m.begin() and .end may return a temporary?

So what you need is

```
class const_iterator {
public:
    const_iterator(const iterator &iter) {}
};
```

Comment: m. begin and m.end return a copy of an iterator. why do I get an error: undefined reference to `mtm::Map<int, int>::iterator::iterator()

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to demonstrate such conversion:

```
#include <iostream>

class iterator {
     public:
        iterator() { i = -1; }
        int i;
        void bar() const { std::cout << "iterator::bar() " << i << std::endl; }
};

class const_iterator : public iterator {
public:
        const_iterator(int ii) : i(ii) {}
        const_iterator(const iterator &it) : i(it.i) {}
        const int i;
        void bar() const { std::cout << "const_iterator::bar() " << i << std::endl; }
};

void foo(const const_iterator &it) {
        it.bar();
}

int main() {
        iterator it;
        it.i = 777;
        foo(it);
        return 0;
}
```